# avatar displays outside of targeted area

Tags: plugins, php, avatar

I use this micro message system script and I want to add an avatar to it, however, my lack of PHP knowledge is making this difficult.

The code I use to display an avatar is:

```
userphoto_thumbnail($user_info, $before = '', $after = '', $attributes = array(width => '40', height => '40'), $default_src = '')
```

And I want to inject this avatar to this part of the message script (inside a loop):

```
$r = $r . '<tr id="wpam-reply-' . $post->post_ID . '-' . $count . '" ' . $style . '>';
$r = $r . '<td style="padding:10px 0 10px 10px; width:40px;"><span title="' . $user_info->display_name . ' (' . $user_info->user_login . ')">' . userphoto_thumbnail($user_info, $before = '', $after = '', $attributes = array(width => '40', height => '40'), $default_src = '') . '</span></td>';
$r = $r . '<td>' . wpam_get_message($reply, $user_info, $options, 2) . '</td>';
$r = $r . '</tr>';
```

If you look at the second line, you will see how I added it there. However, this does not return the avatar where it should be. It appears outside everything else. Maybe because it returns a string rather than data? I am not sure as I am only just familiarising myself with PHP terminology.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, on the HTML output, the avatar images appear outside of the table, when they should be inside the `<td style="padding:10px 0 10px 10px; width:40px;">` tag.

**EDIT 2:** Someone pointed out that `userphoto_thumbnails prints out the image, while I am trying to concatenate it. Its being printed out when I'm creating the string, so it's appearing in the wrong place. So I tested:

```
echo '<tr id="wpam-reply-' . $post->post_ID . '-' . $count . '" ' . $style . '>';
echo '<td style="padding:10px 0 10px 10px; width:40px;"><span title="' . $user_info->display_name . ' (' . $user_info->user_login . ')">' . userphoto_thumbnail($user_info, $before = '', $after = '', $attributes = array(width => '40', height => '40'), $default_src = '') . '</span></td>';
echo '<td>' . wpam_get_message($reply, $user_info, $options, 2) . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

But this did not work either. I am certain that I have not added the avatar code to the script correctly, can you assist?

Comment: please also post the full code of the function `userphoto_thumbnail()` - for your purpose, this needs to `return` the avatar instead of printing it

Comment: @Michael userphoto is a plugin, according to its documentation: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-photo/  it prints out the image. How can I solve this issue without changing the core script of userphoto (if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a native WordPress function to do exactly what it sounds like you're trying to do.

You need to replace

```
userphoto_thumbnail($user_info, $before = '', $after = '', $attributes = array(width => '40', height => '40'), $default_src = '')
```

with

```
get_avatar($user_info->ID,40)
```

Check here for your future reference - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar